# PlantUML images in markdown BitBucket's wiki with Gravizo

Tags: markdown, graphviz, plantuml

I'm trying to put my *PlantUml* diagrams in the Wiki of *BitBucket* using *Markdown*. To do that, I use the *[Gravizo](http://www.gravizo.com/#howto)* service. *Gravizo* uses Graphviz to render graphs. It supports DOT, PlantUML, UMLGraph syntax and SVG in JSON format.

This is a test diagram:

```
@startuml;
Scraper -> Server: ciao
@enduml
```

I have my diagram code stored in a file of the repo ([diagram.uml](https://bitbucket.org/hub21dev/scraper-news-server/raw/documentation/whole_process.uml)).

The syntax should be correct, since in the PlantUML viewer works ([watch demo](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDiUOAJYvAB4WjKj2rKmXEBIfBBR9IICvCpEToICrB0Ie00000))

Hower, in markdown, it shows a broken image. I really don't get what's wrong.

This is the Markdown code I use, with the syntax `http://g.gravizo.com/source?file_url_with_uml`

```
![image](http://g.gravizo.com/source?https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Fhub21dev%2Fscraper-news-server%2Fraw%2Fdocumentation%2Fwhole_process.uml)
```

Is there a way to debug what's the error?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried visiting http://g.gravizo.com/source?https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Fhub21dev%2Fscraper-news-server%2Fraw%2Fdocumentation%2Fwhole_process.uml  yourself? It doesn't look like it's working to me.

Comment: that's the problem. I don't know why it's not working. plantUML syntax seems correct

Comment: This has nothing to do with Markdown (and I'm not sure why you're using the [tag:graphviz] tag either). You need to get the image rendering on gravizo.com (whatever that is). Focus on that.

Comment: Gravizo uses Graphviz to render graphs. It supports DOT, PlantUML, UMLGraph syntax and SVG in JSON format. In Gravizo Test, the syntax is correct

Comment: If the syntax is correct this looks like an error with the Gravizo service. I suggest contacting them.